# Can I lime wash a slate tile floor?

Tags: flooring, slate

Is it possible to use lime wash on slate tile floors? We are renovating a home and we’re wanting to try this but I’m uncertain if it can be done on slate.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure it can be done, the real question is will it give you the effect you're after, right?

Before committing to the entire floor, and possibly ending up with something that you *really* don't want, I'd suggest picking up a single piece of slate, as similar as possibly to your flooring, and test it on that to see how it comes out.

As far as I know, "slate is slate", so when I say "similar", I'm talking about finish and texture. If your flooring is somewhat rough, find a piece with similar roughness, if it's very smooth, pick up a very smooth piece.

Comment: And after you've tested "what happens when you finish it" set it on something (cardboard, carpet?) so it won't crack, and test how it holds up to foot traffic...which would be my big concern with "ways to make a slate floor look awful; the limewash edition" - I envision dark footpaths and lighter un-trafficked  areas after some not very long period of time.